# How create an instance of an abstract class with internal members using remoting / proxy?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I was playing around with Microsoft Entity framework 4 and at some point i want to create a fake instance of ObjectStateEntry using a proxy or FormatterServices and faced with the issues that follow:

1. The class has internal abstract members therefore creating a proxy ends up with type having not-implemented members. Therefore, throws exception during `CreateInstance`.
2. Can't use `FormatterServices.GetUinitializedData` as it is an abstract class.

Would love to know, if are there any other option available ?

Answer (score 0):

Here I wrote down my answer as soon as I saw your question title `How create an instance of an abstract class`, the answer is `No, you can't create an instance of an abstract class.`

Comment: You can create the instance of abstract class through creating a proxy (like how any proxy tool does), but if you have internal members in that abstract class then you can't if you have no options for adding `InternalVisibleTo` attribute in the target library (you need source access to do so). I was looking, if you can create the instance of abstract class by any other means in that regard. Also, Danny thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried any mocking framework such as [Rhino Mocks](http://www.ayende.com/projects/rhino-mocks.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, Vinay  i did tried Rhino Mocks, i was just curious to know and the above case is true for all tools Moq, Rhino, JustMock. I searching if there is any way out.

Comment: Just googling around threw this link - http://www.dimecasts.net/Casts/CastDetails/20. You need to see if it throw something useful.
Typically, its advisable to test against interface rather than classes, although I can see it does not apply out here.

Comment: Yes, it is not it. I was looking for something with the exact issue.